# Excel VBA Date format: Hyphen as separator gives wierd substitution result

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba, date-format

Excel 2007.

I want a macro to put today's date in the current cell formatted as dd-mmm-yy, 
e.g. 30-Oct-14.

The code I have is simple :

'ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")'

For some reason this returns "30 Oct 14" with spaces instead of hyphens.

Similar formats work correctly. e.g

dd-mm-yy gives 30-10-14,
dd~mmm~yy gives 30~Oct~14

The cells actual value is set to "10 30 2014"

Can anyone give me a simple workaround, and if possible, explain why this is happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781234/how-to-concatenate-datemm-dd-yyyy-with-time-hhmmss-using-vba/19784256#19784256

Answer (score 1):

Excel is automatically converting that text you inputting with the macro into a date (and then applying a date format.  To force excel to view it as text, prepend a single quote to the date string:

```
ActiveCell.Value = "'" + Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")
```

Alternatively, set the format of the cell to text type first:

```
ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveCell.Value = Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy")
```

Comment: Thanks. Both options display correctly, though the second, without the single quote, is what I need. I'd upvote/mark as solved if I had the reputation...